# bind custom function to dynamically loaded elements

Tags: jquery

I have written a simple function:

```
function inputChanged()
  {
    $('input').change(function(){
      $(this).addClass('changed');
    });
  }
```

I am adding forms dynamically to a div and would like to bind the function to the added forms, I have tried like this:

```
// add a new form on click
$('.addForm').live({
    click: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("<div>").load("directory/theform.html", function() {
            $("#theForms").prepend($(this).html());
                    // i am calling the function here...
            $("#theForms form:last").validate().inputChange();
        });
    }
});
```

This is not working for me... How can I bind this function to the dynamically loaded forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom jQuery functions like this:

```
jQuery.fn.inputChange = function() {         
    $(this).change(function(){
        $(this).addClass("changed");
    });         
    return this; 
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
$("#theForms form:last").inputChange();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am getting an error message in firebug: $("#RecommendationForm form:last").validate().inputChange is not a function

Comment: Are you sure that `validate` is a function? Can you try removing `validate` and just use `inputChange` to check.

Comment: Thanks, I removed validate(), and it worked. I put validate() back in, but called it last, and everything worked. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Change your first function to:

```
function inputChanged()
{
  $('input').live('change', function(){
    $(this).addClass('changed');
  });
}
```

Or better yet, use jQuery 1.7's new `on()` method insteda.

Comment: When I try this, I am getting a message: $("#RecommendationForm form:last").validate().inputChanged is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".addForm").live("click",function(e){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jquery do you have?

You use events-maps which was added in 1.4.3. See here http://api.jquery.com/live/